# Rails - Building a helper that breaks long words/URLs with <WBR>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my app sends out emails. If there is a very long word or a long URL, it is breaking the email viewing experience by not letting the iphone zoom ad tighten in.

Here's what I've come up with so far but it's not working, thoughts?

**Helper**

```
def html_format(string, max_width=12)
  text = string.gsub("\n", '<br />').html_safe.strip

  (text.length < max_width) ?
  text :
  text.scan(/.{1,#{max_width}}/).join("<wbr>")

  return text
end
```

**View**

```
<%= html_format(@comment.content) %>
```

Comment: instead of `string.gsub("\n", '<br />')`, you can use `simple_format()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [method I found online](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/87492) that seems to work well for splitting long strings with `<wbr>`:

```
def split_str(str, len = 10)
  fragment = /.{#{len}}/
  str.split(/(\s+)/).map! { |word|
    (/\s/ === word) ? word : word.gsub(fragment, '\0<wbr />')
  }.join
end
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it does not work. Doesn't change the output. Did you get this  to work? or just find via a Google Search?

Comment: I got it to work. [Here's a Gist with the function and output](https://gist.github.com/31a948c997850a390089).

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/wrapping-text-with-regular-expressions/) shows how to wrap long words with regular expressions.